# How to get objects to show up as one of 3 colors or more

Tags: node-editor, particles, shaders

So if I were to have a particle system and I had it emitting a object that has emission shader on it how would I get the emitted particles to be one of 3 colors with out having to create 3 particle systems and 3 cubes

Giant cow films 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Input -> Particle Info -> Random* socket.

You can move colorramp slider to adjust presence of the color

[image]