# Multiple colors on particles

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine, emission

So, I have a simple emission texture applied to a particle system and I was wondering, is there a way to make your particle emitter emit a random variety of colors?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46774/cycles-random-material-with-alpha-texture

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/153631/1853

Comment: It does! Thank you!